# Looking for a formula to efficiently discretize a clothoid segment

Tags: differential-geometry

Considering a clothoid, given by the equations

- $x(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\left |\sigma  \right |}} C(\frac{\sigma s}{\sqrt{\pi \left | \sigma \right |}})$ and
- $y(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\left |\sigma  \right |}} S(\frac{\sigma s}{\sqrt{\pi \left | \sigma \right |}})$

where $s$ designates the arc-length and $\sigma$ is the clothoid parameter (sharpness) that inflates or shrinks the clothoid. ($C(t)$ and $S(t)$ are the Fresnel integrals. $C(t)=\int_{0}^{t}cos(\frac{\pi}{2}u^2) du$ and $S(t)=\int_{0}^{t}sin(\frac{\pi}{2}u^2) du$)

For further processing I need to discretize a particular part of the curve given by these formulas, i.e. render it into a sequence of straigt
line segments so that the following holds:
Given

1. the clothoid parameter $\sigma$,
2. an upper bound for deviation (to be further explained) $\varepsilon_{max}$ and
3. a "starting point" $s_{from}$ (in terms of arc length rather than a coordinate) for each straigt line segment to be computed

I need to find a maximum $\Delta_{s}$ so that the maximum deviation $\varepsilon$ (that is, the distance between the straigt line segment (in blue) starting at $s_{from}$ and ending at $s_{to}$ and the enclosed clothoid arc (in green) segment) does not exceed $\varepsilon_{max}$.

[Diagram: Finding a segmented straight line approximation for a clothoid that is accurate by $\varepsilon$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2FS9.png)

I would really appreciate any hint on how this is done. Closed form solutions would be preferable of course.